# subfig and subfloat stopping doc compiling

Tags: errors, subfloats

I have a nice little tiled image sequence that relies on `\usepackage{subfig}` and `\usepackage[countmax]{subfloat}` being declared.

Is it that `[countmax]` is trying to run against the whole doc and this is too much?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}\usepackage[countmax]{subfloat}
\begin{document}

\def \seq1width{0.325}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_1}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-0.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_2}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-1.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_3}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-3.jpeg}} \\
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_4}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-6.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_5}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-9.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_6}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-10.jpeg}} \\
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_7}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-12.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_8}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-13.jpeg}} &
\subfloat[]{\label{fig:image_9}\includegraphics[width=\seq1width\textwidth]{./pupbot_1-15.jpeg}}

\end{array}$
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}
\caption{\label{fig:chinese_dragon_pupbot_sequence_1} Chinese dragon puppet-robot cyclical motion sequence.}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile in a standalone doc (as you see the code above) it works fine but when I try to declare these packages (as you see in the code below) at the start of my `main.tex` and `\input{}` everything in the code between `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` into the document I get this error:

> ! Paragraph ended before \sf@setref was complete. 
>   \par l.46 I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
>   control sequence to too much text.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis}

\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}

\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[countmax]{subfloat}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} 
\title{\ttitle}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setstretch{1.3} 

%...etc
```

Comment: Replacing the `Thesis` class with `book`, your code works fine here. Can you turn your example into a minimal, compilable example that demonstrates the problem? That is, remove all unnecessary packages, and fill in `%...etc` with just the code that causes the error.